# Logging: Kibana integration with FluentD and Elasticsearch - how to integrate (Kubernetes) in a test environment?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

In a Kubernetes Docker Desktop **TEST** environment, I configured Fluentd, Elasticsearch and Kibana. To add an index pattern, I get this error message:

> **Security needs to be enabled** in order to add Elastic Agent
> integrations

I have everything installed, how to just add an index pattern to the already existing Elasticsearch (FluentD) stream? This is just for a testing environment on my local Windows Docker Desktop Kubdernetes environment.

I tried many solutions as suggested in [posts like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73520701/3143823).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - finally! Security settings were not useful/needed in this test config.

I hope this will help you as well for discovering (Kubernetes) Docker logs in via FluentD > Elasticsearch > Kibana.

This works for a logging stack with FluentD > Elasticsearch v7 > Kibana v7.

- First check that the FluentD works. This [excellent video on FluentD configs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kmHvXdAzIM) explains how you can check whether you configured FluentD rightly. In [this article](https://medium.com/@dijin123/fuentd-elasticsearch-kibana-centralized-logging-for-kubernetes-containers-97ba1d359a29) you can read about the same info.
- I used the configs for FluentD, Elasticsearch v7 and Kibana v7 from this [github repo](https://github.com/dijin123/kubernetes/tree/main/Fluentd-Kubernetes/dockerfiles).
- You can then check whether Elasticsearch works using URL's like:

  - http://localhost:9200/ => gives status
  - http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty => gives indices. "Fluentd" should be in the list. If not, change the configuration of Elasticsearch.
    [image]
  - http://localhost:9200/_search?q=counter => should give many logs on the sample application "counter".
    [image]
- Go to Kibana (http://localhost:5601)

  - Menu > Integrations > containers > Elasticsearch Logs > Tab: windows > Button: Discover (or Check data)
  - You may have to enter "fluentd k8s" in an index.

Et voilà - you have the logs!

An example: just type the following in the search box: kubernetes.namespace_name=default and kubernetes.container_name=count

[image]